# Code scraping oddsportal using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code scrapes the website `www.oddsportal.com` for betting odds and historical games.

code:

```
import os
import threading
from math import nan
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def __del__(self):
        self.driver.quit()  # clean up driver when we are cleaned up
        # print('The driver has been "quitted".')


threadLocal = threading.local()


def create_driver():
    the_driver = getattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', None)
    if the_driver is None:
        the_driver = Driver()
        setattr(threadLocal, 'the_driver', the_driver)
    return the_driver.driver


class GameData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []
        self.country = []
        self.league = []


def generate_matches(pgSoup, defaultVal=None):
    evtSel = {
        'time': 'p.whitespace-nowrap',
        'game': 'a div:has(>a[title])',
        'score': 'a:has(a[title])+div.hidden',
        'home_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)',
        'draw_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:not(.hidden)+div:nth-last-of-type(3)',
        'away_odds': 'a:has(a[title])~div:nth-last-of-type(2)',
    }

    events, current_group = [], {}
    pgDate = pgSoup.select_one('h1.title[id="next-matches-h1"]')
    if pgDate: pgDate = pgDate.get_text().split(',', 1)[-1].strip()
    for evt in pgSoup.select('div[set]>div:last-child'):
        if evt.parent.select(f':scope>div:first-child+div+div'):
            cgVals = [v.get_text(' ').strip() if v else defaultVal for v in [
                evt.parent.select_one(s) for s in
                [':scope>div:first-child+div>div:first-child',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(2):nth-last-of-type(2)',
                 ':scope>div:first-child>a:nth-of-type(3):last-of-type']]]
            current_group = dict(zip(['date', 'country', 'league'], cgVals))
            if pgDate: current_group['date'] = pgDate

        evtRow = {'date': current_group.get('date', defaultVal)}

        for k, v in evtSel.items():
            v = evt.select_one(v).get_text(' ') if evt.select_one(v) else defaultVal
            evtRow[k] = ' '.join(v.split()) if isinstance(v, str) else v
        evtTeams = evt.select('a div>a[title]')
        evtRow['game'] = ' – '.join(a['title'] for a in evtTeams)
        evtRow['country'] = current_group.get('country', defaultVal)
        evtRow['league'] = current_group.get('league', defaultVal)

        events.append(evtRow)
    return events


def parse_data(url, return_urls=False):
    browser = create_driver()
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    browser.get(url)
    soup = bs(browser.page_source, "lxml")

    game_data = GameData()
    game_keys = [a for a, av in game_data.__dict__.items() if isinstance(av, list)]
    for row in generate_matches(soup, defaultVal=nan):
        for k in game_keys: getattr(game_data, k).append(row.get(k, nan))
    if return_urls:
        if return_urls:
            a_cont = soup.find('div', {'class': 'tabs'})
            if a_cont is None:
                a_tags = []
            else:
                a_tags = a_cont.find_all('a', {'class': 'h-8', 'href': True})
            urls = [
                'https://www.oddsportal.com' + a_tag['href'] for a_tag in a_tags
                if not a_tag['href'].startswith('#')  # sections in current page
                and 'active-item-calendar' not in a_tag['class']  # current page
            ]
            print(pd.DataFrame(urls, columns=['urls']))
        return game_data, urls
    return game_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    games = None
    pool = ThreadPool(5)
    # Get today's data and the Urls for the other days:
    url_today = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer'
    game_data_today, urls = pool.apply(parse_data, args=(url_today, True))
    game_data_results = pool.imap(parse_data, urls)

    ############################ BUILD  DATAFRAME ############################
    game_data_dfList, added_todayGame = [], False
    for game_data in game_data_results:
        try:
            game_data_dfList.append(pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__))
            if not added_todayGame:
                game_data_dfList += [pd.DataFrame(game_data_today.__dict__)]
                added_todayGame = True
        except Exception as e:
            game_n = len(game_data_dfList) + 1
            print(f'Error tabulating game_data_df#{game_n}:\n{repr(e)}')
        # finally: pass ## [ redundant ]
    try: games = pd.concat(game_data_dfList, ignore_index=True)
    except Exception as e: print('Error concatenating DataFrames:', repr(e))
    ##########################################################################

    print('!?NO GAMES?!' if games is None else games)
    # ensure all the drivers are "quitted": 
    del threadLocal  # a little extra insurance 
    import gc  

    gc.collect()
```

Is there a better way to write function definitions?

Also, this code inconsistently scrapes data even after specifying `browser.implicitly_wait(10)`.
Is there a better way to implicitly wait for `n` seconds and (until the page loads) and then scrape the data?

Comment: There are [other questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=Oddsportal) attempting the same thing. Have you read them?